# How to create approle assignments programmatically using MS graph API?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am building an application to manage Azure AD with our Custom UI.I have created a application on Azure AD and was able to do operations like creating APPs and APP roles programmatically using the Microsoft Graph REST API Beta,but could not create approle assignments using the documenation in the following link, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/serviceprincipal-post-approleassignments?view=graph-rest-beta. Can you please guide me to achieve my requirement

Comment: any resolution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(*Updated on 2020-06-25 to reflect availability and recommended approach on Microsoft Graph v1.0.*)

To create an app role assignment using Microsoft Graph v1.0, you can make the following API request on the resource app's service principal:

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals/{id-resource}/appRoleAssignedTo
Content-type: application/json

{
  "principalId": "id-principal",
  "resourceId": "id-resource"
  "appRoleId": "id-app-role"
}
```

When you are granting an app role assignment to another service principal (i.e. an app-only permission grant), `id-principal` is the `id` of the **servicePrincipal** for the client app (the app which is being granted the application permission), `id-resource` is the `id` of the **servicePrincipal** for the resource app (e.g. the API, such as Microsoft Graph), and `id-app-role` is the `id` of the **appRole** (in this case, the application permission) you want to assign to the client. (The [app role](https://learn.microsoft.com/graph/api/resources/approle?view=graph-rest-1.0) can be retrieved from the `appRoles` attribute of the **servicePrincipal** for the resource app/API.)

Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/graph/api/serviceprincipal-post-approleassignedto?view=graph-rest-1.0

Comment: "id-resource is the id of the ServicePrincipal object for the resource app (e.g. the API, such as Microsoft Graph)"..Can you please share more details about this..How do I get this value ,where can I find it etc

Comment: If you're querying the Microsoft Graph API directly, one approach to retrieve this object is to GET `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/servicePrincipals?$filter=servicePrincipalNames/any(n:n eq 'https://graph.microsoft.com')`. Alternatively, the filter `$filter=appId eq '00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000'` would also work.

Comment: Hi  Philippe Signoret,Can you also please help me in deleting approle assignments programatically using graph api..

Comment: Is there still an issue with adding additional roles today?

Comment: @jbooker as an alternative you can use the endpoint [/appRolesAssignedTo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/serviceprincipal-post-approleassignedto?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) under the v1.0 Graph API which the documentation points out is the recommended way.

Comment: @TomW Good point, I've updated the answer to reflect these updates to the API (and the docs).